# PowerShell - Passing a variable to an Invioke-Command

Tags: powershell, media-queries

For some reason when I try to use the $scanpath variable after the Get-ChildItem in the below code, it doesnt work. But if I put the actual path in place of $scanpath, it works. What am I doing wrong? Both the $computer and $savepath variables work fine.

```
$computer = 'Server'
$scanpath = 'P$\Directory\Directory\Z'
$savepath = 'C:\Z-Media.csv'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -scriptblock {Get-ChildItem $scanpath -recurse -include *.mp3,*.wma,*.wmv,*.mov,*.mpg,*.ogg,*.jpg -force | select FullName, Length | Sort-Object { [long]$_.Length } -descending} | Export-Csv $savepath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt work"?  Do you get an error message in PowerShell, can you share what that message is?

Comment: It just came back with an empty file and no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$scanpath` is not in the same scope as the script block. You have 2 ways to fix this:

## PowerShell 3+ - The `Using` Scope Modifier

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -scriptblock {Get-ChildItem $Using:scanpath -recurse}
```

See [about_Scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) for more information.

> Using is a special scope modifier that identifies a local  variable in
>   a remote command. By default, variables in remote commands are assumed
>   to be defined in the remote session.

## Any Version - Parameters

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -scriptblock {param($thisPath) Get-ChildItem $thisPath -recurse} -ArgumentList $scanpath
```

You can give a script block parameters, just like a function. `Invoke-Command` takes an `-ArgumentList` parameter which passes the values into the scriptblock's parameters.

Comment: $Using:scanpath is what I needed. Thank you!